# English language in Air Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've added Air Date picker in my project. By default the language of the plugin is Russian.

Following the documentation, I tried to change it into English but it still language remains Russian.

```js
$('.datepicker-here').datepicker({
  language: 'en',
  minDate: new Date()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' class='datepicker-here' data-language='en' />
```

Any other people having same issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to import for English language
`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/i18n/datepicker.en.min.js`

Ok, it has changed quite a bit since I used it last time.

Answer (score 2):

Need to add a separate file with `en` locale - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/i18n/datepicker.en.js:

```js
$('.datepicker-here').datepicker({
  language: 'en',
  minDate: new Date()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/i18n/datepicker.en.js"></script>


<input type='text' class='datepicker-here' data-language='en' />
```